# Convert repetitive pattern into JSON file with multiple arrays in Python

Tags: python, json, regex, python-re

I do have a large file of configuration which is saved in a repetitive pattern as shown below example

```
SLAVE="abc"
    SSI_SENDER="X"
    SSI_RECEIVER="Y"
    COMMENT=""
        SENDER_EXT="Z"
            SENDER_COMMENT="L"
        SENDER_EXT="P"
            SENDER_COMMENT="M"
        RECEIVER_EXT="A"
            RECEIVER_COMMENT=""
        RECEIVER_EXT="B"
            RECEIVER_COMMENT="D"
        SSI_DATA="Q"
            SSI_DATA_COMMENT=""
                MESSAGEID="D"
                    MESSAGE_COMMENT=""
                MESSAGEID="W"
                    MESSAGE_COMMENT=""
        SSI_DATA="V"
            SSI_DATA_COMMENT="" 
                MESSAGEID="K"
                MESSAGE_COMMENT=""

SLAVE="def"
    SSI_SENDER="sd"
    SSI_RECEIVER="PL"
    COMMENT=""
        SENDER_EXT="AB"
            SENDER_COMMENT=""
        SENDER_EXT="CD"
            SENDER_COMMENT=""
        RECEIVER_EXT="KL"
            RECEIVER_COMMENT=""
        RECEIVER_EXT="ML"
            RECEIVER_COMMENT=""
        SSI_DATA="AI"
            SSI_DATA_COMMENT=""
                MESSAGEID="VV"
                    MESSAGE_COMMENT=""
                MESSAGEID="CC"
                     MESSAGE_COMMENT=""
```

There are few things to keep in mind, there can be many

- For every loop starting from SLAVE till next loop, We can have many SENDER_EXT, RECEIEVER_EXT, SSI_DATA, and the MESSAGE ID
- SENDER_ID array in JSON should contain all the SENDER_EXT along with SENDER_COMMENT
- RECEIVER_ID array in JSON should contain all the RECEIVER_EXT along with RECEIVER_COMMENT
- SSI_DATA array in JSON contains all the SSI_DATA and which further contains information like MESSAGEID and MESSAGE_COMMENT in its subarray

I am able to get the output in a single JSON file with no multiple arrays when there is only SENDER_EXT, RECEIVER_EXT, SSI_DATA but not when they come more than once

Using the python code

```
import re
import json

# Read from file or use the dummy data
with open("../data/input/ssi_demo.cfg", "r") as f:
    s = f.read()

field_labels = [
                'SLAVE',
                'SSI_SENDER', 
                'SSI_RECEIVER', 
                'COMMENT',
                'SENDER_EXT',
                'SENDER_COMMENT',
                'RECEIVER_EXT',
                'RECEIVER_COMMENT',
                'SSI_DATA',
                'SSI_DATA_COMMENT',
                'MESSAGEID'
                ]

# Define regex pattern and compile for speed
pat = '="(.*)"\n\s*'.join(field_labels) + '="(.*)"'
#print(pat)
pat = re.compile(pat)
#print(pat)
data=pat.findall(s)

# Prepare a list of dicts: each dict for a single block of data
d = [dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(field_labels, field_values)) for field_values in data]
text = json.dumps({'data': d}, indent=2)
#print(text)
# Write to a json file
with open('../data/output/ssi_output_demo.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)

print("JSON Created at data/output")
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "SLAVE": "abc",
      "SSI_SENDER": "X",
      "SSI_RECEIVER": "Y",
      "COMMENT": "",
      "SENDER_ID":[
                {"SENDER_EXT": "Z","SENDER_COMMENT": "L"},
                 {"SENDER_EXT": "P","SENDER_COMMENT": "M"},
                ],
      "RECEIVER_ID":[
                   {"RECEIVER_EXT": "A","RECEIVER_COMMENT": ""},
                   {"RECEIVER_EXT": "B","RECEIVER_COMMENT": "D"}
                ],

      "SSI_DATA": [
                    "Q":{"MESSAGEID": "D",MESSAGE_COMMENT=""},
                    "V":{"MESSAGEID": "K",MESSAGE_COMMENT=""}
                    ]
    
    },
```

Comment: Is the indentation in the input file important for interpreting it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, Not really.. Just shared the file content as it is, if it can help in re pattern

Comment: if they're always in order and formatted like that, you could just use string replacement to turn it into a JSON string directly.  of course, it'll be safer to use regex to extract it all, and chunk and collect the lists into dictionary comprehensions.  not sure how much faster it'll be.  do you have to do any manipulation on it before sending it to JSON?

Comment: No manipulation needed on the data, just need to present the data in json format described above

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to deal with this kind of parsing is not via a regex, but rather treating it as a context-free grammar. You can then use parsers such as PyParsing or Lark to parse it. Here's an example of how to do it with Lark:

```
from lark import Lark
import lark 

grammar = """start: slave +
slave: "SLAVE" "=" ESCAPED_STRING (ssi_sender|ssi_receiver|comment)* 
ssi_sender: "SSI_SENDER" "=" ESCAPED_STRING 
ssi_receiver: "SSI_RECEIVER" "=" ESCAPED_STRING 
comment: "COMMENT" "=" ESCAPED_STRING (sender_ext|receiver_ext|ssi_data)+
receiver_ext: "RECEIVER_EXT" "=" ESCAPED_STRING receiver_comment
receiver_comment: "RECEIVER_COMMENT" "=" ESCAPED_STRING
sender_ext: "SENDER_EXT" "=" ESCAPED_STRING sender_comment
sender_comment: "SENDER_COMMENT" "=" ESCAPED_STRING
ssi_data: "SSI_DATA" "=" ESCAPED_STRING ssi_data_comment
ssi_data_comment: "SSI_DATA_COMMENT" "=" ESCAPED_STRING message+ 
message: "MESSAGEID" "=" ESCAPED_STRING message_comment
message_comment: "MESSAGE_COMMENT" "=" ESCAPED_STRING   

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING
%import common.WS
%import common.NEWLINE
%ignore WS 
%ignore NEWLINE """


p = Lark(grammar, parser='lalr', debug=True)
res = p.parse(text)

def tree_to_dict(tree):
    if isinstance(tree, lark.Tree):
        if len(tree.children) > 1:
            return {tree.data: [tree_to_dict(c) for c in tree.children]} 
        else:
            return {tree.data: tree_to_dict(tree.children[0])} 
    return tree.value[1:-1]
tree_to_dict(res)
```

The output of this parser, after being converted to a dictionary, is given below. You can easily manipulate it to a slightly different structure if you'd like to.

```
{'start': [{'slave': ['abc',
    {'ssi_sender': 'X'},
    {'ssi_receiver': 'Y'},
    {'comment': ['',
      {'sender_ext': ['Z', {'sender_comment': 'L'}]},
      {'sender_ext': ['P', {'sender_comment': 'M'}]},
      {'receiver_ext': ['A', {'receiver_comment': ''}]},
      {'receiver_ext': ['B', {'receiver_comment': 'D'}]},
      {'ssi_data': ['Q',
        {'ssi_data_comment': ['',
          {'message': ['D', {'message_comment': ''}]},
          {'message': ['W', {'message_comment': ''}]}]}]},
      {'ssi_data': ['V',
        {'ssi_data_comment': ['',
          {'message': ['K', {'message_comment': ''}]}]}]}]}]},
  {'slave': ['def',
    {'ssi_sender': 'sd'},
    {'ssi_receiver': 'PL'},
    {'comment': ['',
      {'sender_ext': ['AB', {'sender_comment': ''}]},
      {'sender_ext': ['CD', {'sender_comment': ''}]},
      {'receiver_ext': ['KL', {'receiver_comment': ''}]},
      {'receiver_ext': ['ML', {'receiver_comment': ''}]},
      {'ssi_data': ['AI',
        {'ssi_data_comment': ['',
          {'message': ['VV', {'message_comment': ''}]},
          {'message': ['CC', {'message_comment': ''}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: It does, but I am looking at the regex solution to get this working! thanks for your help